# FFmpeg: Trying to encode all video files in folders and subfolders

Tags: command-line, scripts, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying the following:

- Encode all videofiles that are in the folder/directory and below (in
  subfolders/directories)
- only encode videofiles bigger than 2 GB
- encode to h265 including all audio en subtitle tracks into an .mkv file (done)
- and put all original files in a seperate folder in 1 place. (done)

I'm a real noob and I started as follows.

```
set -e
origdir="/home/tr4/Downloads/test"
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for vid in *.{MOV,mov,MP4,mp4,m2t,MTS,mts,mkv}; do  
 noext="${vid%.*}"    
 ffmpeg -i "$vid" -c:v hevc_nvenc -crf 23 -c:s copy -c:a copy "${noext// /_}_new.mkv"
    mv "$vid" "$origdir"
done
```

But I can not get it to:

1. go into subfolders
2. check for 2GB or bigger size files

Any help would greatly be appreciated!
Cheers
Dave

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.